# AWS Session token expired while running terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, terraform, token, amazon-rds

Using AWS session token in terraform. The RDS restoration is taking more than an hour and session token get expired in the meantime. Due to this the tf state file is also not getting updated in s3. Is there a way to run tf apply in background so that we can refresh token at regular intervals and the operation does not fail?

```
11:07:25    status code: 400, request id: PF3V9137RT1HVB3W, host id: SeXwAFlokygO5NjyKppBD/kYvFl/i9nrh81YSf7Szta6y5Wfd20ssxmFYYwhg+XysuPMvb1uuJo=
11:07:25  
11:07:25  
11:07:25  Error: Failed to persist state to backend.
11:07:25  
11:07:25  The error shown above has prevented Terraform from writing the updated state
11:07:25  to the configured backend. To allow for recovery, the state has been written
11:07:25  to the file "errored.tfstate" in the current working directory.
11:07:25  
11:07:25  Running "terraform apply" again at this point will create a forked state,
11:07:25  making it harder to recover.
11:07:25  
11:07:25  To retry writing this state, use the following command:
11:07:25      terraform state push errored.tfstate
11:07:25  
11:07:25  
11:07:25  
11:07:25  Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
11:07:30  
11:07:30  Error releasing the state lock!
11:07:30  
11:07:30  Error message: failed to retrieve lock info: ExpiredTokenException: The security token included in the request is expired
11:07:30    status code: 400, request id: C7JE11FDGLPTU672G4781LOR73VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
```

Comment: One option is to extend the maximum session duration. On IAM side, you can set the role's maximum session duration up to 12 hours and then on the terraform AWS provider configuration you can set duration_seconds argument inside the AWS provider's assume_role configuration block.

Comment: @Jenneth Yes i have that option in mind, but the role it is currently using is used by some other services as well and instead of creating a new role, i was hoping to come up with alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got a workaround by breaking down the process in two steps. The creation was taking huge time as i was creating a multi-AZ RDS instance. As a solution:

- First we can use terraform to create a single-AZ instance.
- Then again use it to modify the instance to become multi-AZ.

This worked for me.